# Count of Records in Controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have a controller below that mimics the Case Comments related list on a Visualforce page.  I would like to be able to get a count of the related list records so I can conditionally display the column headers in my related list, or at least be able to identify when the related list has no records.  Can anyone help me figure out how to update the controller to do that?  Thanks,

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class VF_AcctSvcsCaseCommentsController {

public Id caseId {get; set;}
public cComments[] comments{get{

List<cComments> comments = new List<cComments>();
for(CaseComment comment : [Select LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Id, LastModifiedBy.Name, IsPublished, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Id, CreatedBy.Name, CommentBody From CaseComment c where ParentId = :caseId order by c.LastModifiedDate desc])
{
cComments tempcComment = new cComments();
tempcComment.cComment = comment;

// Build String to display.
tempcComment.commentText = '<b>Created By: <a href=\'/' + comment.CreatedBy.Id + '\'>' + comment.CreatedBy.Name + '</a> (' + comment.CreatedDate.format() + ') | ';
tempcComment.commentText += 'Last Modified By: <a href=\'/' + comment.LastModifiedBy.Id + '\'>' + comment.LastModifiedBy.Name + '</a> (' + comment.LastModifiedDate.format() + ')</b><br>';
tempcComment.commentText += comment.CommentBody;

if(comment.IsPublished)
tempcComment.PublicPrivateAction = 'Make Private';
else
tempcComment.PublicPrivateAction = 'Make Public';
//Add to list
comments.add(tempcComment); 
}
return comments;
}

set;
}

public PageReference NewComment()
{
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/00a/e?parent_id='+ caseId + '&retURL=%2F' + caseId);
pr.setRedirect(true);
return pr;
}

public PageReference deleteComment()
{
Id commentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CommentId_d');

for(cComments Comment : comments)
{
if(Comment.cComment.Id == commentId)
{   
delete Comment.cComment;    
break;
}
}

PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + caseId);
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}   

public PageReference makePublicPrivate()
{
Id commentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CommentId_p');
for(cComments Comment : comments)
{
if(Comment.cComment.Id == commentId)
{   
Comment.cComment.IsPublished = !Comment.cComment.IsPublished;
if(Comment.cComment.IsPublished)
Comment.PublicPrivateAction = 'Make Private';
else
Comment.PublicPrivateAction = 'Make Public';

update Comment.cComment;    
break;
}
}
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + caseId);
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
}

public class cComments {

public CaseComment cComment {get; set;}
public String commentText {get; set;}
public String PublicPrivateAction {get; set;}
}
}
```

Comment: J.Neilan -a friendly aside -- properly indenting your code is much appreciated by the community

Comment: Sorry.  I neglected to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add this property:

```
public Integer commentCount
{
    get
    {
        return (comments == null) ? 0 : comments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments should never be null, so just return its size?

Comment: Thanks!  Where would I add that in my controller?

Comment: @sfdcfox Actually, since `comments` is assigned as if a local variable, the posted code looks like it should *always* be `null`. Also NPE is annoyingly difficult to debug in `Visualforce`.

Comment: @J.Neilan Add it as you would any other property (e.g. `comments`, `caseId`, etc.)

Comment: One other question, any idea how to mimic the "No records to display" message that appears in a related list when it has no records?  I am using a pageBlockTable in my VF Component to mimic the Case Comments related list.

Comment: I'd try a conditionally rendered `apex:pageMessage` tag.